# sql select query attempt for distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

```html
Table Data 
<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <td>9Code</td><td>10Code</td><td>10Approximate</td><td>10NoMap</td><td>10Combination</td><td>10Scenario</td><td>10ChoiceList</td><td>9Approximate</td><td>9NoMap</td><td>9Combination</td>
    </tr>

<tr><td>04181</td><td>A493</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>A493</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>B960</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>B960</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>J200</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
<br><br>
Desired Table Data
<table border=1>
  <tr>
  <td>9Code</td><td>10Code</td><td>10Approximate</td><td>10NoMap</td><td>10Combination</td><td>10Scenario</td><td>10ChoiceList</td><td>9Approximate</td><td>9NoMap</td><td>9Combination</td>
    </tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>A493</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>B960</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td><td>NULL</td></tr>
<tr><td>04181</td><td>J200</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>1</td></tr>
  </table>
```

I hope the above displays as a table.  I'm trying to run a query to select all of the columns with the distinct 10Code column.  If there are two duplicate 10Code column values then choose the one that is null.  So when I run the sql query Select  distinct([10Code])   from  MyTable I get the desired results BUT when I add more columns to the query such as select distinct ([10Code]), [10Approximate] from MyTable, I get all of the rows.  I want to some how group the entries with count[10Code] >0 then show all columns. Here's the hard part ***When the column has more than 1 occurrence, choose the row that has the NULL value in column [9Approximate]***.

How do I get the remaining columns.

My attempt:
`select [10Code], COUNT([10Code]) AS NumOccurrences FROM MyTable GROUP BY [10Code]
HAVING ( COUNT([10Code]) > = 1 )`

Comment: The above does not display as a table

Comment: run code snippet to see the table

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `[...]` quoted identifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you grouping rows data agregates from many rows to one, if you want to get some column you shuld provide apropriate agregation function and add column to group by.

Another way is to join the grouped results with source data by code and take values from the appropriate rows:

```
select * from
    (
        select 10Code, COUNT(10Code) AS NumOccurrences 
        FROM test.table GROUP BY 10Code
    ) grouped
join test.table src on 
    src.10Code = grouped.10Code 
    and (src.9Approximate is null or grouped.NumOccurrences == 1)
```

Comment: There are 5 entries in the table. Of the entries, 2 of them has 2 occurrences and 1 of them has 1 occurrence.  The entry with the 1 occurrence does not have a null value in src.9Approximate column. I want 3 entries in my result.  See the two tables in my original question.    The second table is the desired result.  The script you provided does not give the desired result.  Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @userDEV, I again updated answer with given your clarification